# How do you append the first pattern of a regular expression to the end of a line using sed?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a .fasta (text) file containing DNA sequence data in the format as follows:

```
>uce-8374_Genus_species
ACGTACGTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTACGATCGCGGTATATCGGCGATTCGATCG

>uce-239_Genus_species
ATCGTAGCATGCGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTCGCGGTACGCATGTCTGACTGCGTCTGGTCGTACGATTACTACGACTGCG

>uce-83_Genus_species
ATCGATCTAGCGTAGCATGCGATCGATATCTGCGATCGACTCGATGCATGCATGCATCGATGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTA

>uce-902_Genus_species
AGCTGACTAGCTGGCGATACTGGCGATATCGGATTACGCGGCATATCGAGCGAGTCGATCGATGCATCTGATGCAGC
```

I am trying to append everything before the **first** underscore, preceded by a `|` to only the end of the lines have the `>`. So for example, the first sequence would read:
`uce-8374_Genus_species|uce-8374`, followed by the DNA sequence beneath it. Is there a way to do this in sed? I tried storing `^[^_]+(?=_)` into a variable, but it didn't work and just kept appending `^[^_]+(?=_)` to the end of the line instead of the pattern itself. Any help, as well as explanations (as I am new to regex) would be helpful. If there is a better way to go about this, I am open to other options!

So far, I have tried (I will just show the first DNA sequence, but I am wanting to change all of them):

```
sed -E 's/species/species|^[^_]+(?=_)/' sample_file.fasta
```

Result: `uce-8374_Genus_species|^[^_]+(?=_)`

and I have also tried:

```
x="^[^_]+(?=_)"
sed -E "s/species/species|$x/" "sample_file.fasta"
```

Result: `uce-8374_Genus_species|^[^_]+(?=_)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Perl, sed doesn't support the PCRE lookahead syntax `(?=_)` but you could fake it as follows:

- match `>` anchored to the start of the line `^>`
- then match and capture zero or more non-`_` characters `([^_]*)`
- then match everything else `.*`

then replace with

- the entire matched pattern `&`
- followed by literal `|` and then the first captured group `\1`

So

```
$ sed -E 's/^>([^_]*).*/&|\1/' sample_file.fasta 
>uce-8374_Genus_species|uce-8374
ACGTACGTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTACGATCGCGGTATATCGGCGATTCGATCG

>uce-239_Genus_species|uce-239
ATCGTAGCATGCGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTCGCGGTACGCATGTCTGACTGCGTCTGGTCGTACGATTACTACGACTGCG

>uce-83_Genus_species|uce-83
ATCGATCTAGCGTAGCATGCGATCGATATCTGCGATCGACTCGATGCATGCATGCATCGATGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTA

>uce-902_Genus_species|uce-902
AGCTGACTAGCTGGCGATACTGGCGATATCGGATTACGCGGCATATCGAGCGAGTCGATCGATGCATCTGATGCAGC
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! If you don't mind, can you explain what this is doing? specifically the second and third part of the `sed` syntax here?

Comment: @Justin please see updated answer